# I need to add the value in the textfield into a drop down list in android

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist, android-spinner

I have one spinner,text field and a button. On click of the button, the text entered in the texfield has to be added to the spinner. I have used ArrayList to add the text. But the application crashes on click of the button.The other two spinners are just dummy.

The Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;
     Button add;
     EditText subject;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     // Spinner element
       spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
       spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
       spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
       add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    // Spinner click listener

       //spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       //spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                   int position, long id) {
               // On selecting a spinner item
               String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

               // Showing selected spinner item
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Selected Subject : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
       });
       add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


         Context context;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String content = subject.getText().toString();
            List list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(content);
            ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        }
       });



        }
    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
                //do something here
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                //optionally do something here
            }
        });
      }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

The XML is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="attended all classes??" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="169dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="" >
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="169dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Add"


        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. If you could post your Logcat stack trace on the error, then we can give you a more accurate answer

Comment: `context` is `null`. You can just use `v.getContext()` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared context and not instantiated it, thus it is null. If you see NullPointerException in you LogCat try the following

```
ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

So replace it with

```
ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment, you should always post the logcat with your question when your app crashes. Here, it looks like the problem is that `context` is `null`. You declare it here

```
Context context;
```

but you never initialize it. But there is no need for this extra variable anyway as you can get the `Context` from the `View` clicked with `v.getContext()` inside your `onClick()`.

```
ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

[See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext())

> Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.

**Helpful Links**

[What is a NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

[Unfortunately my app has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)